# Numpy Advanced Indexing: same index used multiple times in +=

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

Suppose you have the following code

```
a = np.ones(8)
pos = np.array([1, 3, 5, 3])

a[pos] # returns array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), where the 2nd and 4th el are the same
a[pos] +=1
```

The last instruction returns

```
array([ 1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  1.])
```

But I'd like that assignments over same indices to be summed up, so as to obtain

```
array([ 1.,  2.,  1.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  1.])
```

Someone has already experienced this same situation?

Comment: Look into `np.add.at`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick :)

Comment: @Divakar If you want to write an answer, I'll delete my community wiki.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Would be a dup. Looking for it.

Comment: It would be easier to look for duplicates (or for the questioner to find an appropriate solution) if there were a "numpy-integer-indexing" tag... :D

Comment: I agree :) that's why I couldn't found one :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html)

> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand `a` for elements
>   specified by `indices`. For addition `ufunc`, this method is equivalent
>   to `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements
>   that are indexed more than once.

```
np.add.at(a, pos, 1)

print(a)
array([ 1.,  2.,  1.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  1.])
```

Do note that the function works in-place.